# Align websites layout on the profile preferences page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, russian-stackoverflow, preferences

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current

> [image]

Probably, right now appears only on Stack Overflow на Русском, because of the localization. But would be nice to make this layout flexible in general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm doing a light refactor on profiles, and this is a good edge case I didn't find in testing. I'll get this fixed up soon!

Comment: Hello there, Aaron. Any updates? )

Comment: Sorry it took a little longer than I'd hoped but it should be fixed now!